# sapply vs. lapply while reading files and rbind'ing them

Tags: r, sapply, rbind, read.csv

I followed Hadley's thread: [Issue in Loading multiple .csv files into single dataframe in R using rbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23190280/issue-in-loading-multiple-csv-files-into-single-dataframe-in-r-using-rbind) to read multiple `CSV` files and then convert them to one dataframe. I also experimented with `lapply` vs. `sapply` as discussed on [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega).

Here's my first CSV file:

```
dput(File1)
structure(list(First.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"C"), class = "factor"), Last.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "D"), class = "factor"), Income = c(55L, 
23L, 34L, 45L, 44L), Tax = c(23L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L), Location = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Americas", "AP", "EMEA", "LATAM"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("First.Name", "Last.Name", 
"Income", "Tax", "Location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Here's my second CSV file:

```
dput(File2)
structure(list(First.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"C"), class = "factor"), Last.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("B", "D"), class = "factor"), Income = c(55L, 
55L, 55L, 55L, 55L), Tax = c(24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L), Location = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Americas", "AP", "EMEA", "LATAM"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("First.Name", "Last.Name", 
"Income", "Tax", "Location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Here's my code:

```
dat1 <-",First.Name,Last.Name,Income,Tax,Location\n1,A,B,55,23,EMEA\n2,C,D,23,21,EMEA\n3,A,D,34,22,Americas\n4,A,D,45,24,LATAM\n5,A,D,44,25,AP"
dat2 <-",First.Name,Last.Name,Income,Tax,Location\n1,A,B,55,24,EMEA\n2,C,D,55,24,EMEA\n3,A,D,55,24,Americas\n4,A,D,55,24,LATAM\n5,A,D,55,24,AP"

tc1 <- textConnection(dat1)
tc2 <- textConnection(dat2)

merged_file <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(tc1,tc2), read.csv))
```

While this works beautifully, I wanted to change `lapply` to `sapply`. From the above thread, I realize that `sapply` would change the read factors from `csv` file to matrices, but I am unsure why the fields are flipped. For instance, `Income` field occupies row#3 and row#8, but are not in one column.

Here's the code:

```
tc1 <- textConnection(dat1)
tc2 <- textConnection(dat2)

# change lapply to sapply    
merged_file <- do.call(rbind, sapply(list(tc1,tc2), read.csv))
```

Here's the output:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    2    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    2    2    2    2
 [3,]   55   23   34   45   44
 [4,]   23   21   22   24   25
 [5,]    3    3    1    4    2
 [6,]    1    2    1    1    1
 [7,]    1    2    2    2    2
 [8,]   55   55   55   55   55
 [9,]   24   24   24   24   24
[10,]    3    3    1    4    2
```

I'd appreciate any help. I am fairly new to R and not sure what's going on.

Comment: Why do you want to change `lapply` to `sapply`?  `lapply` is the appropriate function here, and it's more efficient.  Btw, `paste` is vectorized.

Comment: @RichScriven - I am just experimenting to understand the reason why the output is different when I use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

Comment: *"While this works beautifully"* It doesn't even work at all, as a reproducible example. We don't have your paths so it will fail. It's easiest to read dataframes from a `textConnection()` instead of a file. I edited your code.

Comment: The issue had nothing to do with factors, it's generic sapply vs lapply. Duplicate of [Why does sapply return a matrix that I need to transpose...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140371/why-does-sapply-return-a-matrix-that-i-need-to-transpose-and-then-the-transpose)

Answer (score 1):

The issue had nothing to do with factors, it's generic `sapply` vs `lapply`.
Why does `sapply` get it so wrong whereas `lapply` gets it right? **Remember in R, dataframes are lists-of-columns.** and each column can have a distinct type.

- `lapply` returns a list-of-columns to `rbind`, which does the concatenation correctly. It keeps corresponding columns together. So your factors emerge correctly.
- `sapply` however...

  - **returns a matrix of numeric**... (since matrices can only have one type, unlike dataframes)
  - ...which, worse still, [**has an unwanted transpose**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140371/why-does-sapply-return-a-matrix-that-i-need-to-transpose-and-then-the-transpose)
  - so `sapply` turns your two 5x6 input dataframes into transposed 6x5 matrices (columns now correspond to rows)...
  - with all data coerced to numeric (garbage!).
  - then `rbind` row-"concatenates" those two garbage 6x5 matrices of numeric into one very-garbage 12x5 matrix. Since columns have been transposed into rows, row-concatenating the matrices combines datatypes, and obviously your factors are messed up.

Summary: just use `lapply`